# Is it better to use class components or functional components in react?

Tags: reactjs

Currently, I am building a website app that would take the user appointment request for a hospital. One of the pages in this appointment request would be to assess the patient, I did it using multiple radio buttons and labels, are there any tips you can advise to me to make this work efficiently? Here is a sample of my code. I am a beginner in react js and looking for ways to optimize this code. Advance Thank you to those who would answer.

```html
export default function DentistQuestions(props){
    const [hasMouthSore, sethasMouthSore] = useState(""); 
    const [hasJawPain, sethasJawPain] = useState("");
    const [swollenFace, setSwollenFace] = useState("");
    const [sensitiveTeeth, setSensitiveTeeth] = useState("");
    const [brokenTeeth, setBrokenTeeth] = useState("");
    const [dryMouth ,setDryMouth] = useState(""); 
    const [bleedingGums , setBleedingGums] = useState(""); 
    const [badTaste, setBadTaste] = useState(""); 
    const [isSmoker, setIsSmoker] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const cancelHandler = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        props.history.push("/");
        dispatch(removeBasicAppointment());
    }
    const backHandler = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        props.history.push("/medicalCard")
    }
    const onSubmitHandler = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(saveDentistryCheckupRequest());
        props.history.push("/");
    }
    return(
        <div classNameName="bodyform">
        <div className="signup-form">
            <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
               
                <h2>Appointment Request</h2>
                <p>Please fill in this form to create an appointment request!</p>
                <hr/>
                 
                <AppointmentSteps step1 step2 step3 />
                <div className="form-check form-check-inline heads">
                        <label className="title" for="civilwidowed"></label>
                        <div className="option-header">
                            <label className="option">Yes </label>
                            <label className="option">No </label>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div className="form-check form-check-inline heads">
                        <label className="title" for="civilwidowed">Has mouth sores? (singaw) </label>
                        <div className="option-header">
                            <input type="radio" value="this is a value" className="option" name="headache"/> 
                            <input type="radio" className="option" name="headache"/>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div className="form-check form-check-inline heads">
                        <label className="title" for="civilwidowed">Has jaw pain ? </label>
                        <div className="option-header">
                            <input type="radio" value="this is a value" className="option" name="heartattack"/> 
                            <input type="radio" className="option" name="heartattack"/>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div className="form-check form-check-inline heads">
                        <label className="title" for="civilwidowed">Has swollen face or gums ? </label>
                        <div className="option-header">
                            <input type="radio" value="this is a value" className="option" name="nh"/> 
                            <input type="radio" className="option" name="nh"/>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div className="form-check form-check-inline heads">
                        <label className="title" for="civilwidowed">Very sensitive teeth ? </label>
                        <div className="option-header">
                            <input type="radio" value="this is a value" className="option" name="cancer"/> 
                            <input type="radio" className="option" name="cancer"/>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div className="form-check form-check-inline heads">
                        <label className="title" for="civilwidowed">Has broken teeth ? </label>
                        <div className="option-header">
                            <input type="radio" value="this is a value" className="option" name="chest"/> 
                            <input type="radio" className="option" name="chest"/>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div className="form-check form-check-inline heads">
                        <label className="title" for="civilwidowed">Has dry mouth ? </label>
                        <div className="option-header">
                            <input type="radio" value="this is a value" className="option" name="cough"/> 
                            <input type="radio" className="option" name="cough"/>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div className="form-check form-check-inline heads">
                        <label className="title" for="civilwidowed">Has bleeding gums ? </label>
                        <div className="option-header">
                            <input type="radio" value="this is a value" className="option" name="bleed"/> 
                            <input type="radio" className="option" name="bleed"/>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div className="form-check form-check-inline heads">
                        <label className="title" for="civilwidowed">Has bad taste or breath in mouth ? </label>
                        <div className="option-header">
                            <input type="radio" value="this is a value" className="option" name="badtaste"/> 
                            <input type="radio" className="option" name="badtaste"/>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div className="form-check form-check-inline heads">
                        <label className="title" for="civilwidowed">Is a smoker ? </label>
                        <div className="option-header">
                            <input type="radio" value="this is a value" className="option" name="smoker"/> 
                            <input type="radio" className="option" name="smoker"/>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="textArea" rows="3" placeholder="Enter other details you want to tell the Dentist"></textarea>
                </div>
        
                <div className="form-group">
                    <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg cancelButton" onClick={cancelHandler} >Cancel</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg cancelButton" onClick={backHandler} >Back</button>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Save</button>  
                 </div>

               
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. This community is here to help with specific questions and yours is probably too broad to be answered here. You might want to post your question again on codereview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome sir! I would like to ask if it is better if i would use classful or functional components in handling states. Additionally, i would like to ask for tips in handling form using react  @Apolo

Comment: With so many states, you can use class component as there you can set individual state using `this.seState`, you need not track so many functions.

Comment: No no no, Class component is a no-go and should be avoided. If you want to have a bigger state, just save an object within your useState, instead of having them individually.

Comment: Also, if you deal with a lot of different forms, and you want to clean them up, I'd suggest to use hooks as react-hook-form https://react-hook-form.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for the insights! @ChristianMoen

Comment: Thank you for the insights sir @RajdeepDebnath!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd stick to functional components. It's the new old thing. Class component was previously the only way of having stateful components, and stateless components was for functional components. This is now **deprecated** and there is many reasons why you should continue to use functional components, as they has support for hooks (which has a lot of already made hooks you can take advantage of).

Anyway, I've come up with a solution for your problem, I've not included all of your code, but I'm giving a hint on how it could be solved.

here's a codesandbox of it: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-wind-tqi9g?file=/src/App.js

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function Question({ value, onChange, name, question }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <label className="title">{question}</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name={name} value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function DentistQuestions(props) {
  const [formState, setFormSate] = useState({
    hasMouthSore: false,
    hasJawPain: false,
    swollenFace: false,
    sensitiveTeeth: false,
    brokenTeeth: false,
    dryMouth: false,
    bleedingGums: false,
    badTaste: false,
    isSmoker: false,
    description: false
  });

  function formOnChange(event) {
    setFormSate({
      ...formState,
      [event.target.name]: !formState[event.target.name]
    });
  }

  function printOutState() {
    console.log(formState);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={printOutState}>Print out state</button>
      <Question
        question="Has mouth sores? (singaw)"
        value={formState.hasMouthSore}
        onChange={formOnChange}
        name="hasMouthSore"
      />
      <Question
        question="Has jaw pain ?"
        value={formState.hasJawPain}
        onChange={formOnChange}
        name="hasJawPain"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you having a lot of forms within your codebase, i'd suggest using a hook for solving these problems. (this is only available in functional components). https://react-hook-form.com/ should have a nicely way of dealing with forms :)

Comment: This is a lot of help, Thank you very much for the effort of coding and explaining things to me thoroughly. Very much appreciated!! @ChristianMoen